# NSInvalidArgumentException - "unrecognized selector sent to instance " getting error when passing json data IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi in my application I'm trying to passing json data in to my tableview but its showing like unrecognized selector sent to instance like this.

I have a json data like this.

```
"youtube_videos":[{"id":"1","name":"Little Flower Public School","youtube":"FFTi2Sl8hHw","link":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/FFTi2Sl8hHw\/default.jpg"}]
```

This json have to youtube video id and thumbnail image of the video now I'm trying to view the thumbnail image in my imageview in my tableview but its giving error like

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa72e290
```

This is the code have used to get the json data .

```
    -(void) retrieveData
     {
      NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
      NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

       json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

       imgarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

      for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++) {

       NSString * dd = [[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"youtube"];
       NSString * sspp = [[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"link"];
       NSString * plae =[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
       NSLog(@"%@",dd);

       vv *myimg =[[vv alloc]initWithvideo:dd andtitle:plae andlink:sspp];

       [imgarray addObject:myimg];

    }

     [self.mytableview reloadData];
```

My Json NSlog.

```
json :{
"youtube_videos" =     (
            {
        id = 1;
        link = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/FFTi2Sl8hHw/default.jpg";
        name = "Little Flower Public School";
    },
            {
        id = 2;
        link = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/4oI7xC2wSpw/default.jpg";
        name = "Little Flower Public School";
    },
            {
        id = 3;
        link = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/XCPKMWyF1Lo/default.jpg";
        name = Function;
    }
  );
}
```

Please Tell me how to resolve this issue i have stuck here for long .

Thanks.

Comment: show your full JSON response. It seems you are getting NSDictionary.

Comment: Your JSON seems to be an `NSDictionary`. So why `objectAtIndex:i`? Show all your JSON response.

Comment: @Larme i have updated my json please tell my how to resolve this one

Comment: @Natarajan i have updated my json please tell my how to resolve this one

Comment: @user3614966 Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should update your code as like below. Because of  your `JSON` looks like a `Dictionary`.

```
-(void) retrieveData
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    imgarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray * respArray = [json objectForKey:@"youtube_videos"];

    for (int i=0; i<respArray.count; i++)
    {

        NSString * dd = [[respArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"youtube"];

        NSString * sspp = [[respArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"link"];

        NSString * plae =[[respArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"%@",dd);

        vv *myimg =[[vv alloc]initWithvideo:dd andtitle:plae andlink:sspp];

        [imgarray addObject:myimg];

    }

    [self.mytableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i have used used ur code but its showing error in NSarray like nsmutablearray decalre the selcecto for objectforkey

Comment: Add NSLog (@"json :%@", json); before NSArray * respArray and show the log.

Comment: youtube = 4oI7xC2wSpw;
        },
                {
            "date_time" = "2014-05-07 18:23:56";
            id = 3;
            link = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/XCPKMWyF1Lo/default.jpg";

Comment: Please provide your full log in your question.

Comment: I have updated just now check again. show error log, if it got error again.

Comment: ya thanks a lot its working f9 im also near from Madurai can i a have ur mailid or skype if u dont mind

Comment: in the blog im not finding ur maild or any contact id its only showing mail me thats all

Comment: provide your mail id, i'll send you a mail

Comment: shantharsk1990@gmail.com this is my mail id please send ur mail id

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your response is. Do you get single or multiple records in the json response.
Try this code:

```
-(void) retrieveData
 {
  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
  NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

   json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

   imgarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSString * dd = [json objectForKey:@"youtube"];
   NSString * sspp = [json objectForKey:@"link"];
   NSString * plae =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
   NSLog(@"%@",dd);

   vv *myimg =[[vv alloc]initWithvideo:dd andtitle:plae andlink:sspp];

   [imgarray addObject:myimg];


 [self.mytableview reloadData];
 }
```